# Excessive Pool Pump Current Usage

Tags: pump, pool

A Florida HOA electric bill doubles from $200 to $400 per month.  Powered items for the pool comprise LED lighting and a pool pump.  The electric circuit is for the pool.

Is it reasonable to start the investigation with the pool pump as the culprit?

If the pump is the culprit, what conclusions can one make regarding the excessive use of current?

Comment: If your area has smart electric meters, there is often a way to check historical power usage online.  You might only get a readout for every 15 minutes or so, but it can be enough to show when the high usage started, and if something is running all the time when you only expect it to run for short periods.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check into this. I've found many times that the timer for the pump is at fault. It's supposed to run about 8 hours a day and I've found them running around the clock. The timer motor can also run sporadically, sometimes turning off as it should, other times not doing so.  If the timer is set for multiple on/off sessions, one of the off tabs could be missing. A clogged or dirty filter can also affect operation but not doubling it.

Comment: I agree sometimes someone over rides the controller trying to vacuum and forget to return it to timer mode.